# Rendering React component and using setstate

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React component that fetches some data via an api. Each item in this data array contains a date and some text. Since I wanna display it like:

DAY
--- text
--- text
--- text
DAY
--- text
--- text
--- text

I need to keep track of the last date fetched. What I'm trying for now is to call this function from my **componentDidMount**

```html
setDates() {
    const logs = this.props.activities.map((post) => {
      const currentDate = post.created_at;
      if (this.state.lastDate !== currentDate) {
        return this.setState({
          lastDate: currentDate,
        }, () => (
          <div className="recent__items">
            <div className="recent__date">
              {currentDate} asasas
              </div>
            <Activity key={post.id} data={post} />
          </div>
          ));
      }
      return (
        <div className="recent__items">
          teste
          <Activity key={post.id} data={post} />
        </div>
      );
    });

    this.setState({
      activities: logs,
    });
  }
```

For some reason logs is always an array of null values.

Can someone tell me what's wrong and how can I better do this?

Comment: You're setting the state, then looking in props.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what you want to accomplish with your `setDates` method. You are setting state, but you are also returning JSX from it, asynchronously. What do you want it to accomplish?

Comment: @Tholle both. This is for conditionally returning JSX. It depends on the date and it also should update the state if the date is a new one.